# Database entry error

Tags: ckeditor

What's the problem in this code?
It shows no error while querying, neither does it get stored

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$title=$_POST['title'];
$content=$_POST['content'];

$dbc=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','root','skype')
or die('Error connecting');
$query= "INSERT INTO pages (title,editor) VALUES ('$title', '$content')" 
 or die('Error querying database');
echo '<br>Page saved successfully under the title: '.$title.'<br>';
mysqli_close($dbc);
 }

 ? >
 <form>
  <label for="title">Title</label>
  <input type="text" name="title" required >
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
    <textarea class="ckeditor" name="content" ></textarea>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
```

Comment: I have no mercy for ones flooding SO with super-low-quality questions like this one and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29471532/no-output-from-database-using-ckeditor. You should read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default request method for a form is GET (see [specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-fs-method)). If you want to POST your form you need to explicitly add the method:

```
<form method="post">
```

Otherwise your `$_POST` will always be empty.

Also, you are open to [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).